# GraphQL resolver returning null/nullvalueinnonnullablefield while Rest API returns correct data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, graphql, graphql-java

I am working on a project where I am trying to get a list of todos from my Postgres db. I am using JPA repository in my service which is then being used by my controllers. My controllers work absolutely fine and extract the correct data from my Postgres DB, but when I use the same repository in my GraphQL resolvers, it returns `null`, if I mark the fields as non-required. If I mark them as required, I get the following error.

```
The field at path '/findAllBookmarks' was declared as a non null type, but the code involved in retrieving data has wrongly returned a null value.  The graphql specification requires that the parent field be set to null, or if that is non nullable that it bubble up null to its parent and so on. The non-nullable type is '[Bookmark]' within parent type 'Query'"
```

The following are my service and controllers.

```
    type Bookmark {
        id: String!
        title: String!
        url: String!
        date: String!
    }
    
    
    extend type Query {
        findAllBookmarks: [Bookmark]!,
        findBookMarkById(id: Int): Bookmark
    }
    
    extend type Mutation {
        createBookmark(title: String, url: String, date: String): Bookmark!,
        updateBookmark(id: String, title: String, url: String, date: String): Bookmark!,
        deleteBookmark(id: String): Boolean!
    }
```

BookmarkRepository

```java
    @Repository
    public interface BookmarkRepository extends JpaRepository<Bookmark, Long> {
    }
```

Query

```java
    package com.productivity.Productivity.resolver;
    
    import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver;
    import com.productivity.Productivity.models.Bookmark;
    import com.productivity.Productivity.repositories.BookmarkRepository;
    import com.productivity.Productivity.service.BookmarkService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    @Component
    public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    
        private final BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        public Query(BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository) {
            this.bookmarkRepository = bookmarkRepository;
        }
    
        public Iterable<Bookmark> findAllBookmarks() {
            try {
                return bookmarkRepository.findAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    
        public Bookmark findBookMarkById(String id) {
            Optional<Bookmark> bookmark = null;
            try {
                bookmark = bookmarkRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(id));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return bookmark.orElse(null);
        }
    }
```

This is my first java spring boot project. I have searched a lot but I am unable to fix it. If you think it could be something related to my project structure (application-properties), then this is this
Following are the image links for my rest api result and graphql error

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1xvD0q6.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/DR0OG6A.png]